# Visual Studio display correct sizeof() for target device

Tags: c++, arduino, visual-studio-2017, visualmicro

I am working on a project for Arduino using VS2017 IDE along with Visual Micro. Everything works fine except for annoying errors caused by incorrect `sizeof` values being **displayed in tooltips**, presumably due to how Intellisense is (mis)configured.

For example, mousing over `sizeof(uint16_t)` displays a value of 4, which is wrong by definition. Or even more annoying problem, the following line:

```
//typedefd as 'typedef uint8_t byte;' in Arduino.h
CASSERT(sizeof(byte) == 1) //IDE is convinced it's == 4, though it's ok for compiler
```

would cause an error appear in the Error List tab (before compilation). The compiler itself does not complain. It is able to determine all `sizeof`s correctly - after compiling the Error List tab is free of similar errors.

Is there a way how to configure VS to adhere the target device type sizes in tooltips for the project?

Comment: @UnholySheep According to the definition for `uintXX_t`: "unsigned integer type with width of exactly 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
(provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)" from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), it does sound incorrect (at least for this case - Arduino) to display 4, since the implementation does indeed support integer types of exactly 16 bits width.